# Revit api How to list all connectors in an MEP Family (not FamilyInstance)

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to get a list of connectors, and their associated parameters in an MEP family.  But i am not able to find a way to do that.  Had it been a Family instance, i could have easily done the following:

```
// famInst in an instance of a FamilySymbol.
famInst_conn_lst = famInst.MEPModel.ConnectorManager.Connectors.Cast<Connector>().ToList();
```

Is there a way to access the "MEPModel" or the "ConnectorManager" directly from a Family?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not want to leave this un-answered:

- So for getting the list of connectorElements in a family, you basically need to use family edit and search as such:

```C#
Document famDocEdt = actvDoc.EditFamily(famDoc );
List<Element> connElmnt_lst = null;
            connElmnt_lst = new FilteredElementCollector(famDocEdt).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_ConnectorElem).ToElements().ToList();
```

see: [How to Get ConnectorElements From a Family](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-mep-forum/how-to-get-connectorelements-from-a-family/td-p/11536580#M89174)

For Finding the Associated Parameter you need to use the GetOderedParameters() as seen here:

```C#
 public string get_AssociatedParametersofConnectorElement(Document dstnctFamDocEdt, ConnectorElement connectorElement)
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectorElement != null)
                {
                    var radiusPara = connectorElement.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.CONNECTOR_RADIUS);
                    foreach (FamilyParameter familyPara in dstnctFamDocEdt.FamilyManager.Parameters)
                    {
                        foreach (Parameter associatedPara in familyPara.AssociatedParameters)
                        {
                            if (radiusPara.Id == associatedPara.Id && associatedPara.Element.Id == connectorElement.Id)
                            {
                                //associate parameter found
                                return familyPara.Definition.Name;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
```

[How To Get Associated Parameters](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2016/02/revitapi-how-to-change-radius-of-connectorelement-how-to-get-associated-family-parameter-from-elemen.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the family definition document, every connector is represented by a separate [`ConnectorElement` database element](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/cd7d7579-1058-e8ca-d55a-c3a914843667.htm). So, in the MEP equipment or fitting `RFA` family document, simply run a filtered element collector to retrieve all such elements, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: thanks for a good laugh this morning, i have not heard "Bob's your uncle" expression in a while...  Is there a way to get the "associated parameter" of  ConnectorElement . e.g. "Main Nominal Radius" is associated with one of the connectors in a family.  I am not able to find that within properties or methods of ConnectorElement.

Comment: I don't really know what an associated parameter may be... the API provides a method named [AssociateElementParameterToFamilyParameter](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/a047ea58-0351-b419-d856-85ed23734ee8.htm)... is that what you are after?

Comment: I added an image to original question to show what i am looking for. It is the family parameter that one would Associate to a connector inside a family (Not Family Instance). So in the image, the connector will be attached to "Nominal Radius 1".  Does this help?